# Outlook add-in send emails in background

Tags: outlook-addin

I plan to develop an outlook add-in to send the emails in the background, I don't know if it is possible to do this in the add-in way? I searched google for some information about that, but I didn't find any solution or hints for that. Could you please help me give me a hint or the possibility? thanks

Comment: Which API? COM? Or JS?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I prefer to JS, is that possible?